# Is the JQMIGRATE necessary for Magento 2?

Tags: jquery, magento2.2.3, console

Just out of curiosity: Is the JQMIGRATE necessary for Magento 2?

Because it is complaining about using a deprecated psuedo event. Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

If it's not necessary for Magento 2, how to disable it?

Please let me know your thoughts.